# Can't disable UIWebView caching

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I'm making a series of requests with `UIWebView` and I need to keep `UIWebView`'s cache clear so that I could start each new request from scratch. So before performing every request I'm doing the following:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

But unfortunately it doesn't help. Every time the first request takes approximately 4 seconds while every following request about 1.5 seconds, so obviously the loaded data is being cached somewhere.

I also tried set caching policy for the request explicitly, like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

but it doesn't help as well. The very first request takes significantly longer time than the following ones. Just like without setting caching policy for the request at all.

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies)
    {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed`. This specifies that storage in `NSURLCache` is not allowed in any fashion, either in memory or on disk.

↳ [Foundation Framework Reference > NSCachedURLResponse Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCachedURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLCacheStoragePolicy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't get how do I use this constant. NSCachedURLResponse classes instances are created somewhere by iOS without me at all. Should I intercept creation of the cached response objects somehow? Can you please provide more information?

Comment: In your request you might use it like: `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10.0];`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. seems like you are being mistaken. NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed is of type NSURLCacheStoragePolicy and designated to be used NSCachedURLResponse class while NSURLRequest's cachePolicy is NSURLRequestCachePolicy

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do; are you trying to keep the request url response cache cleared, or is it something else entirely? If so then what you've already done should've been sufficient. One more thing you could try is `removeCachedResponseForRequest`, although `removeAllCachedResponses` should have worked.

Comment: I want UIWebView don't use its cache at all. I want it to always perform data loading from a remote server rather than fetching it from some local storage

Comment: Are you positive it's cached? You should check with `currentDiskUsage` and `currentMemoryUsage` for the function.

Comment: I can see that the first request takes about 4 seconds and every following request takes about 1.5 seconds. It makes me think that UIWebView does really do caching

Comment: I don't think you can strictly go off of that; there's more to a url request than just the request and response. You should check the values I mentioned to see if the cached data is actually there.